# Como faço para tipar a props que recebe/altera meu state

Tags: react, typescript

Estou passsando meu `state` como `props` para poder usá-lo para fechar o modal quando clico em fechar, porém sempre que tipo o `state`, a `props` rejeita o estado.

```
const [modalSkills, setModalSkills] = useState<Boolean>(false);
  return (
    <>
      <style.Container>
        {modalSkills && <ModalSkills ModalOn={modalSkills} />}
```

Página do modal abaixo:

```
type Props = {
  ModalOn: React.SetStateAction<Boolean>;
};
const ModalSkills = ({ ModalOn }: Props) => {
  return (
    <style.Container>
      <button onClick={() => ModalOn(false)}>fechar</button>
    </style.Container>[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]
```

Comment: Tente tipar o ModalOn como `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>`.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -2):

Você está passando o estado ao invés da SetStateAction dela:

```
const [modalSkills, setModalSkills] = useState<Boolean>(false);
  return (
    <>
      <style.Container>
        {modalSkills && <ModalSkills ModalOn={setModalSkills} />}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).